# Direct3D9 EndScene hook rendering

Tags: c++, directx, hook, overlay, render

I am hooking a Directx9 Game using vTable hooks. So far, I have been able to successfully hook both "Present" and "EndScene" (and of course, CreateDevice and Direct3dCreate9), however - and here is the catch - as soon as I attempt to actually draw anything (for example, text), my Present hook is no longer being hit. (This may be a built in security routine... I'm not totally sure).

For example... The following code works

```
HRESULT APIENTRY hook_EndScene(IDirect3DDevice9* pInterface){   
    pInterface->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255), 1.0f, 0);
    return orig_EndScene(pInterface);
}
```

Resulting in the screen permanently displaying a white color.
However, attempting to render text (font created in the CreateDevice hook, using the returned IDirect3DDevice9 pointer - I have made sure to use __asm pushad and popad to restore registers), or a sprite, results in the EndScene hook no longer being hit at all.

I am wondering if there is any special code required to ensure the EndScene hook works... And why I can clear the screen, but as soon as I wish to render extra content to it... the hook no longer works (No longer hits breakpoints). The text DOES render successfully... for a split second, before being replaced by a Bink video... the hook no longer working in this case.

I am completely clueless... and would appreciate some help for some more experienced DirectX coders. Thanks.

EDIT Here is my CreateDevice Hook just in case

```
HRESULT APIENTRY hook_CreateDevice(IDirect3D9* pInterface, UINT Adapter,D3DDEVTYPE DeviceType,HWND hFocusWindow,DWORD BehaviorFlags,D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS* pPresentationParameters,IDirect3DDevice9** ppReturnedDeviceInterface){

HRESULT ret = orig_CreateDevice(pInterface, Adapter, DeviceType, hFocusWindow, BehaviorFlags, pPresentationParameters, ppReturnedDeviceInterface);
__asm pushad
IDirect3DDevice9* d3ddev = *ppReturnedDeviceInterface;
D3DXCreateFont(d3ddev, 30, 0, FW_NORMAL,1,  false,  DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,  DEFAULT_QUALITY,DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, "Arial", &lpfont);   
//We have located the d3ddevice pointer. Now we can hook it!
DWORD* vTable = (DWORD*)*((DWORD*)d3ddev);
HookVTableFunc(vTable, (void*)&hook_EndScene, (void*)&orig_EndScene, 42);
__asm popad
return ret;

}
```

And the EndScene hook that does not work (breaks the hook entirely):

```
LPD3DXFONT lpfont;
HRESULT APIENTRY hook_EndScene(IDirect3DDevice9* pInterface){


static RECT textbox; SetRect(&textbox, 0, 0, 640, 480); 
lpfont->DrawTextA(NULL, "Testing", 22, &textbox, 0, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0,255,255,255));
return orig_EndScene(pInterface);

}
```

Comment: Maybe the application you are hooking calls BeginScene() EndScene() more than once? You could try hooking the Present() call and do all your rendering there.

Comment: Debuggers are very helpful when hooking code

Comment: Many games, other overlays and video recording software use multiple IDirect3DDevice9 interfaces. You need to make sure the font you created is relative to the current device when EndScene is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, I think the problem is you left the alpha on 0?.

My hooking code generates these variables

- fIDirect3DDevice9_EndScene
  **Function Pointer Type**
- foIDirect3DDevice9_EndScene
  **Function Pointer to orginal Function**
- fhIDirect3DDevice9_EndScene
  **Function Pointer to replacement Function**
- vtIDirect3DDevice9_EndScene
  **VTable relative of EndScene**

Using these naming scheme the rest of the functions can also be generated automatically by the macros.

The actual sample/hook (works for 32 and 64 bits):

```
LPD3DXFONT g_Font;
D3DXFONT_DESC FontDesc = {24,
                          0,
                          400,
                          0,
                          false,
                          DEFAULT_CHARSET,
                          OUT_TT_PRECIS,
                          CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                          DEFAULT_PITCH,
                          "Arial"};

void initHook() {
    IDirect3DDevice9* pD3DDevice = .. you got this one
    hookVT(pD3DDevice, IDirect3DDevice9, EndScene);
    D3DXCreateFontIndirect(pD3DDevice, &FontDesc,&g_Font);
}

#undef METHOD
#undef INTERFACE

#define INTERFACE IDirect3DDevice9
#define METHOD EndScene
GEN_HOOK(INTERFACE FAR* This)
{   
    static RECT textbox;
    SetRect(&textbox, 5, 0, 640, 480); 
    g_Font->DrawTextA(NULL, "Testing sadsadsad asd sadas asd sad sad as das dsadas dsa dsadas dasd ", -1, &textbox, DT_CENTER, 0xffffffff);

    CALL_ORGINAL();

    return hr;
}
#undef METHOD
```

I created some helper functions/macros for this job:

```
template<typename func, typename vttype> void changeVTEx(void** vt, vttype n, func target)
{
    DWORD OldProtections = 0;
    VirtualProtect(&vt[n], sizeof(LPCVOID), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &OldProtections);
    vt[n] = (void*)target;
    VirtualProtect(&vt[n], sizeof(LPCVOID), OldProtections, &OldProtections);
}

// preprocessor tools
#define PPCAT_NX(A, B) A ## B
#define PPCAT(A, B) PPCAT_NX(A, B)

#define getVT(ptr) (*(void***)ptr)
#define changeVT(n, target) changeVTEx(getVT(This), n, target)

#define hookVT(ptr, INTERFACE, METHOD) \
{\
    PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(fo, INTERFACE),_), METHOD) = (PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(f, INTERFACE), _), METHOD))(getVT(ptr)[PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(vt, INTERFACE),_), METHOD)]);\
    changeVTEx(getVT(ptr), PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(vt, INTERFACE),_), METHOD), PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(fh, INTERFACE),_), METHOD));\
}

#define GEN_HOOK_(TYPE, ...) \
    PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(f, INTERFACE), _), METHOD) PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(fo, INTERFACE),_), METHOD) = NULL;\
    TYPE STDMETHODCALLTYPE PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(fh, INTERFACE),_), METHOD)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define GEN_HOOK(...) \
    GEN_HOOK_(HRESULT, __VA_ARGS__)

#define UNHOOK \
    changeVT(PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(vt, INTERFACE),_), METHOD), PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(fo, INTERFACE),_), METHOD))

#define REHOOK \
    changeVT(PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(vt, INTERFACE),_), METHOD), PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(fh, INTERFACE),_), METHOD))

#define CALL_ORGINAL_(RET, ...) \
    UNHOOK;\
    RET = PPCAT(This->, METHOD)(__VA_ARGS__);\
    REHOOK;

#define CALL_ORGINAL(...) \
    CALL_ORGINAL_(HRESULT hr, __VA_ARGS__)

// Create function pointer types
#undef INTERFACE
#define INTERFACE IDirect3DDevice9
#undef PURE
#define PURE
#undef THIS_
#define THIS_                   INTERFACE FAR* This,
#undef THIS
#define THIS                    INTERFACE FAR* This
#undef STDMETHOD
#define STDMETHOD(method)       typedef HRESULT (STDMETHODCALLTYPE *PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(f, INTERFACE),_), method))
#undef STDMETHOD_
#define STDMETHOD_(type,method) typedef type (STDMETHODCALLTYPE *PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(f, INTERFACE),_), method))

// 1:1 copy from d3d9.h:
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(THIS_ REFIID riid, void** ppvObj) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,AddRef)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,Release)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(TestCooperativeLevel)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(UINT, GetAvailableTextureMem)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(EvictManagedResources)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetDirect3D)(THIS_ IDirect3D9** ppD3D9) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetDeviceCaps)(THIS_ D3DCAPS9* pCaps) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetDisplayMode)(THIS_ UINT iSwapChain,D3DDISPLAYMODE* pMode) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetCreationParameters)(THIS_ D3DDEVICE_CREATION_PARAMETERS *pParameters) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetCursorProperties)(THIS_ UINT XHotSpot,UINT YHotSpot,IDirect3DSurface9* pCursorBitmap) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(void, SetCursorPosition)(THIS_ int X,int Y,DWORD Flags) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(BOOL, ShowCursor)(THIS_ BOOL bShow) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateAdditionalSwapChain)(THIS_ D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS* pPresentationParameters,IDirect3DSwapChain9** pSwapChain) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetSwapChain)(THIS_ UINT iSwapChain,IDirect3DSwapChain9** pSwapChain) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(UINT, GetNumberOfSwapChains)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Reset)(THIS_ D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS* pPresentationParameters) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Present)(THIS_ CONST RECT* pSourceRect,CONST RECT* pDestRect,HWND hDestWindowOverride,CONST RGNDATA* pDirtyRegion) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetBackBuffer)(THIS_ UINT iSwapChain,UINT iBackBuffer,D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE Type,IDirect3DSurface9** ppBackBuffer) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetRasterStatus)(THIS_ UINT iSwapChain,D3DRASTER_STATUS* pRasterStatus) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetDialogBoxMode)(THIS_ BOOL bEnableDialogs) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(void, SetGammaRamp)(THIS_ UINT iSwapChain,DWORD Flags,CONST D3DGAMMARAMP* pRamp) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(void, GetGammaRamp)(THIS_ UINT iSwapChain,D3DGAMMARAMP* pRamp) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateTexture)(THIS_ UINT Width,UINT Height,UINT Levels,DWORD Usage,D3DFORMAT Format,D3DPOOL Pool,IDirect3DTexture9** ppTexture,HANDLE* pSharedHandle) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateVolumeTexture)(THIS_ UINT Width,UINT Height,UINT Depth,UINT Levels,DWORD Usage,D3DFORMAT Format,D3DPOOL Pool,IDirect3DVolumeTexture9** ppVolumeTexture,HANDLE* pSharedHandle) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateCubeTexture)(THIS_ UINT EdgeLength,UINT Levels,DWORD Usage,D3DFORMAT Format,D3DPOOL Pool,IDirect3DCubeTexture9** ppCubeTexture,HANDLE* pSharedHandle) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateVertexBuffer)(THIS_ UINT Length,DWORD Usage,DWORD FVF,D3DPOOL Pool,IDirect3DVertexBuffer9** ppVertexBuffer,HANDLE* pSharedHandle) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateIndexBuffer)(THIS_ UINT Length,DWORD Usage,D3DFORMAT Format,D3DPOOL Pool,IDirect3DIndexBuffer9** ppIndexBuffer,HANDLE* pSharedHandle) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateRenderTarget)(THIS_ UINT Width,UINT Height,D3DFORMAT Format,D3DMULTISAMPLE_TYPE MultiSample,DWORD MultisampleQuality,BOOL Lockable,IDirect3DSurface9** ppSurface,HANDLE* pSharedHandle) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateDepthStencilSurface)(THIS_ UINT Width,UINT Height,D3DFORMAT Format,D3DMULTISAMPLE_TYPE MultiSample,DWORD MultisampleQuality,BOOL Discard,IDirect3DSurface9** ppSurface,HANDLE* pSharedHandle) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(UpdateSurface)(THIS_ IDirect3DSurface9* pSourceSurface,CONST RECT* pSourceRect,IDirect3DSurface9* pDestinationSurface,CONST POINT* pDestPoint) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(UpdateTexture)(THIS_ IDirect3DBaseTexture9* pSourceTexture,IDirect3DBaseTexture9* pDestinationTexture) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetRenderTargetData)(THIS_ IDirect3DSurface9* pRenderTarget,IDirect3DSurface9* pDestSurface) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetFrontBufferData)(THIS_ UINT iSwapChain,IDirect3DSurface9* pDestSurface) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(StretchRect)(THIS_ IDirect3DSurface9* pSourceSurface,CONST RECT* pSourceRect,IDirect3DSurface9* pDestSurface,CONST RECT* pDestRect,D3DTEXTUREFILTERTYPE Filter) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(ColorFill)(THIS_ IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface,CONST RECT* pRect,D3DCOLOR color) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateOffscreenPlainSurface)(THIS_ UINT Width,UINT Height,D3DFORMAT Format,D3DPOOL Pool,IDirect3DSurface9** ppSurface,HANDLE* pSharedHandle) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetRenderTarget)(THIS_ DWORD RenderTargetIndex,IDirect3DSurface9* pRenderTarget) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetRenderTarget)(THIS_ DWORD RenderTargetIndex,IDirect3DSurface9** ppRenderTarget) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetDepthStencilSurface)(THIS_ IDirect3DSurface9* pNewZStencil) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetDepthStencilSurface)(THIS_ IDirect3DSurface9** ppZStencilSurface) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(BeginScene)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(EndScene)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Clear)(THIS_ DWORD Count,CONST D3DRECT* pRects,DWORD Flags,D3DCOLOR Color,float Z,DWORD Stencil) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetTransform)(THIS_ D3DTRANSFORMSTATETYPE State,CONST D3DMATRIX* pMatrix) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetTransform)(THIS_ D3DTRANSFORMSTATETYPE State,D3DMATRIX* pMatrix) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(MultiplyTransform)(THIS_ D3DTRANSFORMSTATETYPE,CONST D3DMATRIX*) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetViewport)(THIS_ CONST D3DVIEWPORT9* pViewport) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetViewport)(THIS_ D3DVIEWPORT9* pViewport) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetMaterial)(THIS_ CONST D3DMATERIAL9* pMaterial) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetMaterial)(THIS_ D3DMATERIAL9* pMaterial) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetLight)(THIS_ DWORD Index,CONST D3DLIGHT9*) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetLight)(THIS_ DWORD Index,D3DLIGHT9*) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(LightEnable)(THIS_ DWORD Index,BOOL Enable) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetLightEnable)(THIS_ DWORD Index,BOOL* pEnable) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetClipPlane)(THIS_ DWORD Index,CONST float* pPlane) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetClipPlane)(THIS_ DWORD Index,float* pPlane) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetRenderState)(THIS_ D3DRENDERSTATETYPE State,DWORD Value) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetRenderState)(THIS_ D3DRENDERSTATETYPE State,DWORD* pValue) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateStateBlock)(THIS_ D3DSTATEBLOCKTYPE Type,IDirect3DStateBlock9** ppSB) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(BeginStateBlock)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(EndStateBlock)(THIS_ IDirect3DStateBlock9** ppSB) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetClipStatus)(THIS_ CONST D3DCLIPSTATUS9* pClipStatus) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetClipStatus)(THIS_ D3DCLIPSTATUS9* pClipStatus) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetTexture)(THIS_ DWORD Stage,IDirect3DBaseTexture9** ppTexture) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetTexture)(THIS_ DWORD Stage,IDirect3DBaseTexture9* pTexture) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetTextureStageState)(THIS_ DWORD Stage,D3DTEXTURESTAGESTATETYPE Type,DWORD* pValue) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetTextureStageState)(THIS_ DWORD Stage,D3DTEXTURESTAGESTATETYPE Type,DWORD Value) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetSamplerState)(THIS_ DWORD Sampler,D3DSAMPLERSTATETYPE Type,DWORD* pValue) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetSamplerState)(THIS_ DWORD Sampler,D3DSAMPLERSTATETYPE Type,DWORD Value) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(ValidateDevice)(THIS_ DWORD* pNumPasses) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetPaletteEntries)(THIS_ UINT PaletteNumber,CONST PALETTEENTRY* pEntries) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetPaletteEntries)(THIS_ UINT PaletteNumber,PALETTEENTRY* pEntries) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetCurrentTexturePalette)(THIS_ UINT PaletteNumber) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetCurrentTexturePalette)(THIS_ UINT *PaletteNumber) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetScissorRect)(THIS_ CONST RECT* pRect) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetScissorRect)(THIS_ RECT* pRect) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetSoftwareVertexProcessing)(THIS_ BOOL bSoftware) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(BOOL, GetSoftwareVertexProcessing)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetNPatchMode)(THIS_ float nSegments) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(float, GetNPatchMode)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(DrawPrimitive)(THIS_ D3DPRIMITIVETYPE PrimitiveType,UINT StartVertex,UINT PrimitiveCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(DrawIndexedPrimitive)(THIS_ D3DPRIMITIVETYPE,INT BaseVertexIndex,UINT MinVertexIndex,UINT NumVertices,UINT startIndex,UINT primCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(DrawPrimitiveUP)(THIS_ D3DPRIMITIVETYPE PrimitiveType,UINT PrimitiveCount,CONST void* pVertexStreamZeroData,UINT VertexStreamZeroStride) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(DrawIndexedPrimitiveUP)(THIS_ D3DPRIMITIVETYPE PrimitiveType,UINT MinVertexIndex,UINT NumVertices,UINT PrimitiveCount,CONST void* pIndexData,D3DFORMAT IndexDataFormat,CONST void* pVertexStreamZeroData,UINT VertexStreamZeroStride) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(ProcessVertices)(THIS_ UINT SrcStartIndex,UINT DestIndex,UINT VertexCount,IDirect3DVertexBuffer9* pDestBuffer,IDirect3DVertexDeclaration9* pVertexDecl,DWORD Flags) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateVertexDeclaration)(THIS_ CONST D3DVERTEXELEMENT9* pVertexElements,IDirect3DVertexDeclaration9** ppDecl) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetVertexDeclaration)(THIS_ IDirect3DVertexDeclaration9* pDecl) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetVertexDeclaration)(THIS_ IDirect3DVertexDeclaration9** ppDecl) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetFVF)(THIS_ DWORD FVF) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetFVF)(THIS_ DWORD* pFVF) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateVertexShader)(THIS_ CONST DWORD* pFunction,IDirect3DVertexShader9** ppShader) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetVertexShader)(THIS_ IDirect3DVertexShader9* pShader) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetVertexShader)(THIS_ IDirect3DVertexShader9** ppShader) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetVertexShaderConstantF)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,CONST float* pConstantData,UINT Vector4fCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetVertexShaderConstantF)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,float* pConstantData,UINT Vector4fCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetVertexShaderConstantI)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,CONST int* pConstantData,UINT Vector4iCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetVertexShaderConstantI)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,int* pConstantData,UINT Vector4iCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetVertexShaderConstantB)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,CONST BOOL* pConstantData,UINT  BoolCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetVertexShaderConstantB)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,BOOL* pConstantData,UINT BoolCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetStreamSource)(THIS_ UINT StreamNumber,IDirect3DVertexBuffer9* pStreamData,UINT OffsetInBytes,UINT Stride) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetStreamSource)(THIS_ UINT StreamNumber,IDirect3DVertexBuffer9** ppStreamData,UINT* pOffsetInBytes,UINT* pStride) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetStreamSourceFreq)(THIS_ UINT StreamNumber,UINT Setting) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetStreamSourceFreq)(THIS_ UINT StreamNumber,UINT* pSetting) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetIndices)(THIS_ IDirect3DIndexBuffer9* pIndexData) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetIndices)(THIS_ IDirect3DIndexBuffer9** ppIndexData) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreatePixelShader)(THIS_ CONST DWORD* pFunction,IDirect3DPixelShader9** ppShader) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetPixelShader)(THIS_ IDirect3DPixelShader9* pShader) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetPixelShader)(THIS_ IDirect3DPixelShader9** ppShader) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetPixelShaderConstantF)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,CONST float* pConstantData,UINT Vector4fCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetPixelShaderConstantF)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,float* pConstantData,UINT Vector4fCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetPixelShaderConstantI)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,CONST int* pConstantData,UINT Vector4iCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetPixelShaderConstantI)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,int* pConstantData,UINT Vector4iCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(SetPixelShaderConstantB)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,CONST BOOL* pConstantData,UINT  BoolCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetPixelShaderConstantB)(THIS_ UINT StartRegister,BOOL* pConstantData,UINT BoolCount) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(DrawRectPatch)(THIS_ UINT Handle,CONST float* pNumSegs,CONST D3DRECTPATCH_INFO* pRectPatchInfo) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(DrawTriPatch)(THIS_ UINT Handle,CONST float* pNumSegs,CONST D3DTRIPATCH_INFO* pTriPatchInfo) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(DeletePatch)(THIS_ UINT Handle) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(CreateQuery)(THIS_ D3DQUERYTYPE Type,IDirect3DQuery9** ppQuery) PURE;

// Create vtable offsets
#undef STDMETHOD
#define STDMETHOD(method) PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(vt, INTERFACE),_), method),
#undef STDMETHOD_
#define STDMETHOD_(type,method) PPCAT(PPCAT(PPCAT(vt, INTERFACE),_), method),

enum PPCAT(vt, INTERFACE)
{
// 1:1 copy from d3d9.h: replace (THIS* -> ""
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,AddRef)
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,Release)
    STDMETHOD(TestCooperativeLevel)
    STDMETHOD_(UINT, GetAvailableTextureMem)
    STDMETHOD(EvictManagedResources)
    STDMETHOD(GetDirect3D)
    STDMETHOD(GetDeviceCaps)
    STDMETHOD(GetDisplayMode)
    STDMETHOD(GetCreationParameters)
    STDMETHOD(SetCursorProperties)
    STDMETHOD_(void, SetCursorPosition)
    STDMETHOD_(BOOL, ShowCursor)
    STDMETHOD(CreateAdditionalSwapChain)
    STDMETHOD(GetSwapChain)
    STDMETHOD_(UINT, GetNumberOfSwapChains)
    STDMETHOD(Reset)
    STDMETHOD(Present)
    STDMETHOD(GetBackBuffer)
    STDMETHOD(GetRasterStatus)
    STDMETHOD(SetDialogBoxMode)
    STDMETHOD_(void, SetGammaRamp)
    STDMETHOD_(void, GetGammaRamp)
    STDMETHOD(CreateTexture)
    STDMETHOD(CreateVolumeTexture)
    STDMETHOD(CreateCubeTexture)
    STDMETHOD(CreateVertexBuffer)
    STDMETHOD(CreateIndexBuffer)
    STDMETHOD(CreateRenderTarget)
    STDMETHOD(CreateDepthStencilSurface)
    STDMETHOD(UpdateSurface)
    STDMETHOD(UpdateTexture)
    STDMETHOD(GetRenderTargetData)
    STDMETHOD(GetFrontBufferData)
    STDMETHOD(StretchRect)
    STDMETHOD(ColorFill)
    STDMETHOD(CreateOffscreenPlainSurface)
    STDMETHOD(SetRenderTarget)
    STDMETHOD(GetRenderTarget)
    STDMETHOD(SetDepthStencilSurface)
    STDMETHOD(GetDepthStencilSurface)
    STDMETHOD(BeginScene)
    STDMETHOD(EndScene)
    STDMETHOD(Clear)
    STDMETHOD(SetTransform)
    STDMETHOD(GetTransform)
    STDMETHOD(MultiplyTransform)
    STDMETHOD(SetViewport)
    STDMETHOD(GetViewport)
    STDMETHOD(SetMaterial)
    STDMETHOD(GetMaterial)
    STDMETHOD(SetLight)
    STDMETHOD(GetLight)
    STDMETHOD(LightEnable)
    STDMETHOD(GetLightEnable)
    STDMETHOD(SetClipPlane)
    STDMETHOD(GetClipPlane)
    STDMETHOD(SetRenderState)
    STDMETHOD(GetRenderState)
    STDMETHOD(CreateStateBlock)
    STDMETHOD(BeginStateBlock)
    STDMETHOD(EndStateBlock)
    STDMETHOD(SetClipStatus)
    STDMETHOD(GetClipStatus)
    STDMETHOD(GetTexture)
    STDMETHOD(SetTexture)
    STDMETHOD(GetTextureStageState)
    STDMETHOD(SetTextureStageState)
    STDMETHOD(GetSamplerState)
    STDMETHOD(SetSamplerState)
    STDMETHOD(ValidateDevice)
    STDMETHOD(SetPaletteEntries)
    STDMETHOD(GetPaletteEntries)
    STDMETHOD(SetCurrentTexturePalette)
    STDMETHOD(GetCurrentTexturePalette)
    STDMETHOD(SetScissorRect)
    STDMETHOD(GetScissorRect)
    STDMETHOD(SetSoftwareVertexProcessing)
    STDMETHOD_(BOOL, GetSoftwareVertexProcessing)
    STDMETHOD(SetNPatchMode)
    STDMETHOD_(float, GetNPatchMode)
    STDMETHOD(DrawPrimitive)
    STDMETHOD(DrawIndexedPrimitive)
    STDMETHOD(DrawPrimitiveUP)
    STDMETHOD(DrawIndexedPrimitiveUP)
    STDMETHOD(ProcessVertices)
    STDMETHOD(CreateVertexDeclaration)
    STDMETHOD(SetVertexDeclaration)
    STDMETHOD(GetVertexDeclaration)
    STDMETHOD(SetFVF)
    STDMETHOD(GetFVF)
    STDMETHOD(CreateVertexShader)
    STDMETHOD(SetVertexShader)
    STDMETHOD(GetVertexShader)
    STDMETHOD(SetVertexShaderConstantF)
    STDMETHOD(GetVertexShaderConstantF)
    STDMETHOD(SetVertexShaderConstantI)
    STDMETHOD(GetVertexShaderConstantI)
    STDMETHOD(SetVertexShaderConstantB)
    STDMETHOD(GetVertexShaderConstantB)
    STDMETHOD(SetStreamSource)
    STDMETHOD(GetStreamSource)
    STDMETHOD(SetStreamSourceFreq)
    STDMETHOD(GetStreamSourceFreq)
    STDMETHOD(SetIndices)
    STDMETHOD(GetIndices)
    STDMETHOD(CreatePixelShader)
    STDMETHOD(SetPixelShader)
    STDMETHOD(GetPixelShader)
    STDMETHOD(SetPixelShaderConstantF)
    STDMETHOD(GetPixelShaderConstantF)
    STDMETHOD(SetPixelShaderConstantI)
    STDMETHOD(GetPixelShaderConstantI)
    STDMETHOD(SetPixelShaderConstantB)
    STDMETHOD(GetPixelShaderConstantB)
    STDMETHOD(DrawRectPatch)
    STDMETHOD(DrawTriPatch)
    STDMETHOD(DeletePatch)
    STDMETHOD(CreateQuery)
};
```